# How to use mysql IN statement with wpdb update method?

Tags: wordpress

I am using wpdb update method and wish to update records where the id is not found within multiple ids.

So if I wanted to update records where each had an id of `1` I would do for example:

```
$wpdb->update( 
            'wp_my_tables', 
            array( 
                'active' => 0
            ), 
            array( 'id' => 1 ), 
            array( 
                '%d'
            ), 
            array( '%d' ) 
        );
```

But how would I edit that so it does NOT update values where the ids are for example `1,2,3` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a generic query using `$wpdb->query()` and this might be easier in this case.

```
$q = $wpdb->prepare( 'UPDATE wp_my_tables SET foo = %s WHERE id NOT IN (1, 2, 3)', array( 'bar' ) );

$wpdb->query( $q );
```